# $P(A-B>t) < P(A>\frac{t}{2})-P(B>\frac{t}{2})$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, inequality

Is is true that

$$P(A-B>t) < P(A>\frac{t}{2})-P(B>\frac{t}{2})$$

is there any relation between the two sides?

Comment: Try rather $$P(X-Y>x-y) \geqslant P(X>x)-P(Y>y)$$ in particular, $$P(X-Y>2x) \geqslant P(X>x)-P(Y>-x)$$

Comment: Thank you. But I am more interested on finding an upper bound for the probability on the left side.

Comment: You may be so, but I am more interested in inequalities that have the slightest chance of being true...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $A,B$ i.i.d. normal and fix $t$. Then the inequality is false since RHS is 0.